# Why does my public IP not change when changing networks?

Tags: networking, vpn, ip

I am using the laptop configured by my company. I tried accessing a website this morning that said -

> The owner of this website (***website URL here***) has banned your IP address (***my IPV4 address here, confirmed by seraching "IP" on Google***).

I changed from office network to mobile hotspot. I could not access the website even then since I still get the same old IP, on the website error and on google when using the computer. Then I googled for "IP" on both mobile browser and on the computer - both are different. How is the public IP being retained here?

Additional details:

- OS: Windows 7
- VPN Client: Cisco Anyconnect, disconnected
- Additional software suspected for this behavior installed: Triton AP-Endpoint Web

Comment: What do you mean by mobile hotspot? Is that wireless connection at your work location? Is your mobile also configured by your company?

Comment: By mobile hotspot I mean, tethering from my personal (no ties to the company) android phone. And the other network in question is my company's Wifi and Ethernet LAN.

Comment: Normally your external IP address would not change whether you use a wired or wireless network within the same cadastral, that might be your answer.

Comment: Please read the question description. I **did** mention that when looking for my IP on the phone browser directly, I get a different IP. I believe that implies I should see the same IP from the computer when my computer is connected to internet through the phone.

Comment: Maybe the two IP adresses are within the same scope then or owned by the same company? Sorry for misunderstanding, just trying to help.

Comment: I appreciate that. Thank you for trying. I would accept if the phone showed the same as computer but I am having hard time accepting this.